# Laravel 4 Add Method to Class (IoC / Namespaces)

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to figure out how to add a method to a class in a Laravel package, so that all controllers and models that call that class can access the new method.  How do I replace this class in the IoC?

[This is the package in question, Angel CMS.](https://github.com/JVMartin/angel)  The package is my creation, so I can modify it if we need to add aliases or anything to accomplish this.

Let's say I want to add a method to [this class](https://github.com/JVMartin/angel/blob/master/src/models/PageModule.php):

```
vendor/angel/core/src/models/PageModule.php
```

Okay, so I copy the class file to here:

```
app/models/PageModule.php
```

And then I modify the copied file, adding a namespace and the desired `custom_function` method:

```
<?php namespace MyModels;

use Eloquent;

class PageModule extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'pages_modules';

    public static function custom_function()
    {
        return 'It works!';
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using the `MyModels` namespace here.

Then, I run a `composer dump-autoload`.

Next, I open up my `app/routes.php` and register the binding and set up a test route:

```
App::bind('PageModule', function($app) {
    return new \MyModels\PageModule;
});

Route::get('test-binding', function() {
    return PageModule::custom_function();
});
```

But, when visiting the test route, I always receive the same error that the method is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?  Thank you in advance for any help.

**To Clarify:**

I am attempting to *replace* the class application-wide so that all other classes (controllers/models/etc.) that call PageModule will have access to the `custom_function` method.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do it. I checked their `CoreServiceProvider.php` and they didn't do any bindings. They also call create `PageModule` object directly in their controllers using `new PageModule`.

Comment: @Unnawut, the package is mine - I can add anything necessary to make this work.  Do you think I should bind aliases to accomplish easily replaceable classes or how do I go about it?

Comment: This might sound irritating, and I'm sure you would have done it already if it suits your scenario, but what stops you from modifying the PageModule class directly?

Comment: @Unnaawut - This is a composer package, which means that it is overwritten every time it is updated (in the vendor/ folder).  We need to find some way of extending classes differently across dozens of different websites that will need different methods on each of them, so that they aren't overwritten.  This is what the IoC was built for, I just don't understand how to use it.  :(

Comment: Ok, that's pretty much the answer I expected, I'll try write an answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm pretty new to all this IoC, dependency inversion/injection concept too. But I think I've gone through the same struggle before. What I would do, as much as my knowledge allows, is...

Add a constructor to *src/controllers/admin/AdminPageController.php*:

```
protected $pageModule;

public function __construct(PageModule $pageModule)
{
    $this->pageModule = $pageModule;
}
```

Then where you did `$module = new PageModule` in the same file. You replace it with:

```
$module = $this->pageModule;
```

The two modifications above makes use of Laravel's IoC to allow injecting a different PageModule object into your controller, instead of strictly creating PageModule in your code.

Now at this point Laravel should know that when it constructs the AdminPageController, it should create a PageModule and inject into the controller for you.

Since your controller now expects a PageModule class, you can no longer do `class PageModule extends Eloquent` in your app anymore, because even though the name is the same, PHP does not think that it is! You'll need to extend it:

So let's rename your `app/models/PageModule.php` to `app/models/CustomPageModule.php`, and in the file change the class to:

```
class CustomPageModule extends \PageModule {
```

Up to this point, you also have a `CustomPageModule` class that is a child of your package's `PageModule`. All you need to do now is to let Laravel knows that if any controllers ask for `PageModule`, it should serve the controller with your `MyModels\CustomPageModule` instead.

So at the top of your app's `routes.php` file:

```
App::bind('PageModule', 'MyModels\CustomPageModule');
```

Your `AdminPageController` should now be using your `CustomPageModule` and can use whatever public methods that are in there!

---

I'm expecting to be editing this answer heavily since this will be quite a long discussion. My first try at answering above isn't the best code you can write, but I hope it takes the least amount of edit to the original code, and then we can work up from there.

Or fast track by reading up articles like http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories

Comment: By the way this answer was written along with me modifying my project code and it's working. So I hope it would work everywhere.

Comment: Hey thanks so much again @Unnawut.  You got me going in the right direction... I have to replace all occurences of direct `PageModule::` calls within the entire framework to use `$pageModuleModel = App::make('PageModule'); $pageModule::`, similarly to how the constructor dependency injections work.  It's a huge overhaul (I'm going to do it for *all* controllers and models, not just `PageModule`) - but it will be well worth it!  Thanks!

Comment: @Leng Glad it helps! I think this deserves another question by it's own. Even though content about IoC and dependency inversion/injection is all around. I didn't find any specifically on developing easily-extendible packages like building a CMS package.

Comment: @Leng actually, speaking of easily-extendible packages, This [Laravel-Administrator](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator) pop into my mind. Since it's supposed to fit as backend admin for all sorts of Laravel applications, I think you might gain some good ideas from looking at their source code.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks again - that `Laravel-Administrator` package is going to be a huge help to figuring out how to use bindings and namespaces correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a alias for the `PageModule` facade, you should override this alias using your class `\MyModels\PageModule` in your `app/config/app.php` file.

Be careful, it seems like you are overwriting the `PageModule` class instead of extending it. You should probably extend the parent class instead of `Eloquent`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately, there are no facades in the package, and I am indeed trying to *replace* the class so that all other classes that call PageModule load my new class with the custom function.

Comment: Perhaps using aliases on all my classes that I want to be extendable would actually be a good solution?  The complete error message is `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::custom_function()`

Comment: Angel CMS is my package, so I can set up aliases if you think it'd be a cleaner solution!

Comment: Seems like you don't really extends Eloquent... Try to remove the `use` statement and extends Eloquent using `extends \Eloquent` (wild guess)